# Filter store transactions Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have this Core Data stack and I have an observer to observe NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, I would like to filter changes that the user has made to call the mergePersistentHistoryChanges() just when needed, I think it has to be done in the fetchPersistentHistoryTransactionsAndChanges() function but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me. Thank You

```
class PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    private var notificationToken: NSObjectProtocol?
    
    init() {
        notificationToken = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, object: nil, queue: nil) { note in
            Task {
                await self.fetchPersistentHistory()
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let observer = notificationToken {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
    
    private var lastToken: NSPersistentHistoryToken?

    /// A persistent container to set up the Core Data stack.
    lazy var container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let fileContainer = URL.storeURL(for: "group name", databaseName: "CoreData")

        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "CoreData")

        let defaultDirectoryURL = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()

        let localStoreURL = defaultDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Local.sqlite")
        let localStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: localStoreURL)
        localStoreDescription.configuration = "Local"

        // Create a store description for a CloudKit-backed local store
        let cloudStoreDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: fileContainer)
        cloudStoreDescription.configuration = "Cloud"

        // Set the container options on the cloud store
        cloudStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "containerIdentifier")
        cloudStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        cloudStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [cloudStoreDescription, localStoreDescription]

        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }

        // This sample refreshes UI by consuming store changes via persistent history tracking.
        /// - Tag: viewContextMergeParentChanges
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = false
        container.viewContext.name = "viewContext"
        container.viewContext.transactionAuthor = "User"
        /// - Tag: viewContextMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.undoManager = nil
        container.viewContext.shouldDeleteInaccessibleFaults = true
        
        return container
    }()

    private func newTaskContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        // Create a private queue context.
        /// - Tag: newBackgroundContext
        let taskContext = container.newBackgroundContext()
        taskContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        // Set unused undoManager to nil for macOS (it is nil by default on iOS)
        // to reduce resource requirements.
        taskContext.undoManager = nil
        return taskContext
    }

    func save() {
        if self.container.viewContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try self.container.viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(Errors.errorSaving)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchPersistentHistory() async {
        do {
            try await fetchPersistentHistoryTransactionsAndChanges()
        } catch {
            print(Errors.fetchPersistentHistory)
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchPersistentHistoryTransactionsAndChanges() async throws {
        let taskContext = newTaskContext()
        taskContext.name = "persistentHistoryContext"

        try await taskContext.perform {
            let changeRequest = NSPersistentHistoryChangeRequest.fetchHistory(after: self.lastToken)
            let historyResult = try taskContext.execute(changeRequest) as? NSPersistentHistoryResult
            if let history = historyResult?.result as? [NSPersistentHistoryTransaction],
               !history.isEmpty {
                self.mergePersistentHistoryChanges(from: history)
                return
            }
            throw Errors.fetchPersistentHistoryTransactionsAndChanges
        }
    }

    private func mergePersistentHistoryChanges(from history: [NSPersistentHistoryTransaction]) {
        let viewContext = container.viewContext
        viewContext.perform {
            for transaction in history {
                print("Merged by func mergePersistentHistoryChanges ")
                viewContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: transaction.objectIDNotification())
                self.lastToken = transaction.token
            }
        }
    }
}
```